# How to change table content instead of going to the directory

Tags: php, html, css

I accomplished making a table which lists the current directory. What I was hoping is that when I click on the directory, the table would refresh and load the content of the directory instead of going to the actual directory. What is the correct code that I should have used?

```
<?php

function view_size($size)
{
    if($size >= 1073741824)
    {
        $size = @round($size / 1073741824 * 100) / 100 . " GB";
    }
    elseif($size >= 1048576)
    {
        $size = @round($size / 1048576 * 100) / 100 . " MB";
    }
    elseif($size >= 1024)
    {
        $size = @round($size / 1024 * 100) / 100 . " KB";
    }
    else
    {
        $size = $size . " B";
    }
    return $size;
}

function dirlist()
{
    $myDirectory = opendir(".");

    while($entries = readdir($myDirectory))
    {
        $dirListArray[] = $entries;
    }

    $fileCount = count($dirListArray);
    sort($dirListArray);
    print("<p style='color:#CCC;padding:0px;margin:5px;'>$fileCount FILES / FOLDER FOUND</p>");

    print("<table style='color:#FFF' width=100% border=1 cellpadding=5 cellspacing=0 class=whitelinks>\n");
    print("<tr><th>FILE/FOLDER NAME</th><th>FILE TYPE</th><th>FILE SIZE</th></tr>");
    for($index=0;$index<$fileCount;$index++)
    {
        print("<tr><td><a href='./$dirListArray[$index]/.'>$dirListArray[$index]</a></td>");
        print("<td>");
        print(filetype($dirListArray[$index]));
        print("</td>");
        print("<td>");
        print(view_size(filesize($dirListArray[$index])));
        print("</td>");
        print("</tr>\n");
    }
    print("</table>");
}

?>

<html>
<head>

<style type="text/css">
#directory-list-container {
    margin: 7px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 3px solid #000;
    outline: 1px solid #666;
}

#directory-list-content {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 2px solid #666;
}

#directory-list-content a {
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#directory-list-container a:link {
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#directory-list-container a:hover {
    color: #0F0;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#directory-list-container a:active {
    color: #090;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#directory-list-container a:visited {
    color: #DDD;
    text-decoration: none;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<div id="directory-list-container">
    <div id="directory-list-content">
        <?php dirlist(); ?>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

It shows as a table but when I click on a directory or file, it goes to that directory or it opens the file instead of refreshing the table to list the directory of which I have clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click a link it's going to navigate your browser there, and unless you have URL rewriting set up on your server whatever is at that URL will be loaded. You need to use a GET (query) parameter to pass the directory you selected to your PHP file, and use that when displaying the anchors.

I took some liberties with the code below but I believe it does what you wanted. The name of the script is read from the current URL stripped from any query parameters, and a `dir` query parameter is used to pass the folder name on to the script in the anchors. With these combined the URL looks something like this, depending on how you run it:

```
/folder/script.php?dir=foldername%2Ffolder2
```

Note that the value is URL encoded, which in general is a good practice to do whenever you pass arbitrary strings as query parameters. In the code below, the file name output is also wrapped in `htmlspecialchars()` which escapes any HTML characters that the browser might recognize as markup and try to parse as such, causing the page to fall apart.

For added security, I included a call to `ini_set` to change the [`open_basedir`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir) setting to the current directory at run time to avoid directory traversal attacks such as `?dir=../../../../etc/passwd` that could be used to gain access to sensitive system information. While not in your original requirement, I believe this should also be handled in your case, and I strongly suggest keeping this security measure in.

Additionally, there is some handling of dotfiles (`.` and `..`) to make sure the current directory is not listed, and that you cannot navigate up from the base directory.

I also used [HEREDOC](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) to keep the code more readable and efficient than multiple calls to `print`. The only minor inconvenience that comes with that is that you can't put too complex expressions inside the string, so you must move them to a variable above, but I believe that also helps with readability.

```php
<?php

// Credit to http://jeffreysambells.com/2012/10/25/human-readable-filesize-php
function human_file_size($bytes, $decimals = 2) {
  $size = array('B', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB');
  $factor = (int)floor((strlen($bytes) - 1) / 3);

  return round($bytes / pow(1024, $factor), 2).' '.@$size[$factor];
}

function dirlist() {
  // Prevent malicious users from reading files in directories above
  ini_set('open_basedir', __DIR__);

  $baseDirectory = '.'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
  // Get directory from query parameter
  $directoryPath = $baseDirectory.(!empty($_GET['dir']) ? rtrim($_GET['dir'], '\\/').DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR : '');
  $myDirectory = opendir($directoryPath);
  $isTopLevel = $directoryPath === $baseDirectory;

  while ($entry = readdir($myDirectory)){
    if ($entry === '.' || ($isTopLevel && $entry === '..')){
      continue;
    }
    $dirListArray[] = $entry;
  }

  $fileCount = count($dirListArray);
  sort($dirListArray);
  print <<<HTML
    <p class="heading">$fileCount FILES / FOLDER FOUND</p>

    <table width="100%" border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" class="whitelinks">
      <tr>
          <th>FILE/FOLDER NAME</th>
          <th>FILE TYPE</th>
          <th>FILE SIZE</th>
      </tr>
HTML;

  // Get current URL without query parameters
  // Trim everything after and including "?"
  $scriptPath = strtok($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '?');

  foreach ($dirListArray as $indexValue){
    $htmlEncodedIndex = htmlspecialchars($indexValue);
    $fileType = filetype($directoryPath.$indexValue);
    $fileSize = human_file_size(filesize($directoryPath.$indexValue));
    if ($fileType === 'dir'){
      if ($indexValue === '..'){
        // Link to top level, no rectory separator in string
        if (strpos($indexValue, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR) === false)
          $queryParam = '';
        // Link to subdirectory
        else {
          $parts = explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $indexValue);
          array_pop($parts);
          // Assemble query param (make sure to URL encode!)
          $queryParam = '?dir='.urlencode(implode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $parts));
        }
      }
      // Assemble query param (make sure to URL encode!)
      else $queryParam = '?dir='.urlencode($indexValue);
      $href = $scriptPath.$queryParam;
    }
    else $href = $directoryPath.$indexValue;

    print <<<HTML
      <tr>
        <td>
          <a href='$href'>$htmlEncodedIndex</a>
        </td>
        <td>$fileType</td>
        <td>$fileSize</td>
      </tr>
HTML;
  }

  print '</table>';
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <style type="text/css">
    .heading {
      color: #CCC;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 5px;
    }
    #directory-list-container {
      margin: 7px;
      padding: 0;
      border: 3px solid #000;
      outline: 1px solid #666;
    }

    #directory-list-content {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 5px;
      border: 2px solid #666;
    }

    #directory-list-content a,
    #directory-list-container a:link {
      color: #00f;
      text-decoration: none !important;
    }
    #directory-list-container a:hover {
      color: #0F0;
    }
    #directory-list-container a:active {
      color: #090;
    }
    #directory-list-container a:visited {
      color: #DDD;
    }
  </style>

</head>
<body>
<div id="directory-list-container">
  <div id="directory-list-content">
    <?php dirlist(); ?>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you revise it? Can you include the parent directory ".." from the initial load? Because I still need that part, not only when I navigate through a folder from the initial directory. And if possible, make the ".."/"." in the first row of the table. Also can you include an icon before the name of the file/folder? Like if it's a directory there'd be a folder icon beside it, if its a file then have a paper icon beside it? Icon would be on the left side of the name of course. Thanks! Sorry for the numerous request, I'm still learning.

Comment: Your requirements sound very specific and not really fit for Stack Overflow. I strongly encourage you to do some research on your own and attempt to implement these features by yourself.